# Real-Time Updates Not Reflecting on Frontend in Next.js App

Tags: next.js, frontend, backend, vercel

I am working on a nextjs app (nextjs version 13.4.2). In my app, in the pages/api, I have created 3 files - delete.js, process.js, upload.js.

All 3 functionalities work perfectly fine both on my local host and vercel deployment but the only problem is I have to refresh the page manually after each action to see the result on screen. For example, after clicking upload button, the pdf does get uploaded successfully but it still doesn't appear on the frontend of web app, unless I manually refresh the screen.

I want that as soon as the changes happen in the backend, it should reflect in the frontend.

Like if I press delete button, it should delete the file from database and the file should not be visible on the frontend anymore, instead of me having to manually refresh the page for the file to go.

What is the problem here and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question without any code examples is a bit generic, so what you're probably looking for is the concept of data revalidation.

The two main strategies "background revalidation" and "on-demand revalidation" could both be useful for you.

- Background revalidation refreshes the data in a customizable time interval e.g. every 60 seconds.
- On-demand let's you set tags when you fetch some data and later, when data is successfully updated, you can revalidate the tag with `revalidatePath`. Or you can revalidate a whole page with `revalidatePath`.

See the docs for detailed information:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation

Comment: https://srcb.in/AFv21VWImN
This is the code for MyFiles.js where I have provided a button to delete a specific file.

I tried your above solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I still have to refresh the page manually otherwise the file is still visible even after deleting.

Comment: The background revalidation with `revalidate: 10` only refreshes the data every 10 seconds when the page is refreshed. Instead, add a cache tag where you fetch the files and in the `handleDelete` function, revalidate it on success with `revalidateTag`.